# avoid _y and _x in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do a left join like below, but I'm getting `date1_x`, `date1_y` and `date2_x` and `date2_y`. What I want is to replace the column if it exists.

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')
```

df1

```
id, date1, val1,  date2

1,  '2021-03-10', 'XEP', '2021-04-10'
```

df2

```
 id,    date1,      date2
 1,  '2021-09-03', '2021-09-04'
 2,  '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'
 3,  '2021-09-07', '2021-09-08'
```

expected resulting df:

```
1,  '2021-09-03', 'XEP' , '2021-09-04'
```

I tried the code below

```
df11 = df1.set_index('id')
df22 = df2.set_index('id') 
df11.update(df22)
```

But I noticed that my column `id` disappears from my columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combine_first` + `dropna`

```
df1 = df2.combine_first(df1).dropna()[df1.columns]
```

Output:

```
   id        date1   val1         date2
0   1  '2021-09-03'  'XEP'  '2021-09-04'
```

Comment: just using reset_index() would do job and as he said using upadate would be more approriate. And great alternative by the way.

Comment: @Manlai thank you for your suggestion but im my df1 im always gotting emty dataframe

Answer (score 0):

just add this one line it will work.

```
df11 = df1.set_index('id')
df22 = df2.set_index('id') 
df11.update(df22)
df11.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work .

Comment: @naveneeth nanda because the date tooks id column.

Comment: No it wont run the code as it is u'll get it right